# Use `np.diff` but assume the input starts with an extra zero

Tags: python, numpy

Given a series of event times `v`, I can create their interval durations using `np.diff(v)`. Is there a way to have `np.diff` assume the series starts with an implicit `0.`, so that it produces an array that has the same length as `v`?

A manual workaround is:

```
def diff_from_zero(v):
    return np.diff(np.hstack(([0.], v)))
```

Is there a way to use `diff` or another function to have the same result?

Comment: This or directly concatenating diff's result to the first element of your original array which is more or less the same

Comment: I don't have an answer but I notice that the hstack doc says, 'you should prefer np.concatenate or np.stack.'

Comment: Thanks! `hstack` does in fact support the shorthand `np.hstack((0, v))` and concatenate not.

Comment: I like your manual approach. There are many ways of prefixing a vector before `diff`ing (zero `hstack((0,v))`, clamp `hstack((v[0],v))`, wrap `hstack((v[-1],v))`, mirror `hstack((v[1],v))`) and it’s application-dependent. Spelling it out like this should be fine.

Comment: @Emilien Ah that's not the same thing. I figure my title was ambiguous

Comment: Ok I don't really like self-answers but it I found another function that can in fact do this, see the answer. Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given for example:

```
t = np.array([1.1, 2.0, 4.5, 4.9, 5.2])
```

We want to compute the consecutive differences in `t`, including the diff from `0.` to the first element in `t`.

The question gave this way of accomplishing this:

```
>>> np.diff(np.hstack((0, t)))
```

And it could be this too:

```
>>> np.hstack((t[0], np.diff(t)))
```

But the obscurely-named function [`ediff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html#numpy.ediff1d) can do it in one function call:

```
>>> np.ediff1d(t, to_begin=t[0])
array([ 1.1,  0.9,  2.5,  0.4,  0.3])
```

Prepending `t[0]` to the result is the same as computing the difference `t[0] - 0.`, of course. (Assuming `t` is nonempty).

---

Timings (not the motivation of the question, but I was curious)

```
import numpy as np
t = np.random.randn(10000)
%timeit np.diff(np.concatenate(([0], t)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 23.1 µs per loop
%timeit np.diff(np.hstack((0, t)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.2 µs per loop
%timeit np.ediff1d(t, to_begin=t[0])
10000 loops, best of 3: 92 µs per loop
```

Comment: The code for both `diff` and `ediff1d` is python that you can easily study.  `diff` is simpler.  In the base case it is the difference between two slices, `t[1:]-t[:-1]`.

Comment: The equivalent of `hstack` is `np.concatenate(([0],t))`.  `hstack` just makes sure the inputs are `atleast_1d` arrays.

Answer (score 24):

As of 2019, `np.diff` has the arguments `prepend` and `append` that can add a certain value to the array before differentiation. [See the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)

This would append the first value to the array, hence the `diff` operation would return something of len(t) that starts with 0.

```
>>> t = np.array([1.1, 2.0, 4.5, 4.9, 5.2])
>>> np.diff(t, prepend=t[0])
array([0. , 0.9, 2.5, 0.4, 0.3])
```

The `prepend` argument can take other values.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. It is very practical to have all derivatives with the same dimensions as the input.

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up of Matias' answer for arrays of more than one axis :

```
def np_diff(arr: np.array, axis: int):
    return np.diff(
        arr, 
        axis=axis, 
        prepend=np.expand_dims(np.take(arr, 0, axis=axis), axis=axis)
    )
```